# Как вывести текущее время в MS SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

Как вывести текущее время в MS SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```sql
SELECT GETDATE()
```

или так:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

или даже так, для полноты картины:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       SYSDATETIME(),
       SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
       SYSUTCDATETIME(),           
       GETDATE(),
       GETUTCDATE();
```